# Multiplication of large sparse Matrices without null values in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, matrix-multiplication

I have two very sparse distributed matrixes of dimension 1,000,000,000 x 1,000,000,000 and I want to compute the matrix multiplication efficiently.

I tried to create a BlockMatrix from a CoordinateMatrix but it's a lot of  memory (where in reality the non zero data are around ~500'000'000) and the time of computation is enormous.

So there is another way to create a sparse matrix and compute a multiplication efficiently in a distributed way in Spark? Or i have to compute it manually?

Comment: You'll have a better chance of getting a answer if you provide enough details to diagnose the problem. _a lot of memory_ tells us nothing. Not to mention some code could be useful.

Comment: My problem is not the memory but the time of the computation. Anyways I found a strategy to make my matrix less sparse so now I'm able to compute it in less than 30min.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As there is no build-in method in Spark to perform a matrix multiplication with sparse matrixes. I resolved by reduce at best the sparsity of the matrices before perform the matrice multiplication with BlockMatrix (that not support sparse matrix).

Last edit: Even with the sparsity optimization I had a lot of problems with large dataset. Finally, I decided to implement it myself. Now is running very fast. I hope that a matrix implementation with sparse matrix will be implemented in Spark as I think there are a lot of application that can make use of this.

Comment: How did you implement this?

Comment: please post your implementation or hints at least (join to use as outer priduct maybe on coo-matrix)?

Answer (score 0):

You must obviously use a storage format for sparse matrices that makes use of their sparsity.

Now, without knowing anything about how you handle matrices and which libraries you use, there's no helping you but to ask you to look at the linear algebra libraries of your choice and look for sparse storage formats; the "good old" Fortran-based libraries that underly a lot of modern math libs support them, and so chances are that you really have to do but a little googling with *yourlibraryname + "sparse matrix"*.

**second thoughts**:

Sparse matrixes really don't lend themselves to distribution very well; think about the operations you'd have to do to coordinate distribution compared to the actual multiplications/additions.

Also, ~5e8 non-zero elements in a 1e18 element matrix are definitely *a lot of memory*, and since you don't specify how much you consider *a lot* to be, it's very possible there's nothing wrong with it. Assuming you're using the default `double` precision, that's 5e8 * 8B = 4GB of pure numbers, not counting the coordinates needed for sparse storage. So, if you've got ~10GB of memory, I wouldn't be surprised at all.

Comment: I use Spark for Scala as mentioned in the tags. I searched in google but I didn't found anything for multiply a very large sparse matrix efficiently (in parallel)

Comment: well, you should then read the official Spark / MLlib docs; http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html lists a data type to use for sparse matrices, which is the Coordinate Matrix you were using in the first place. So I was assuming you weren't talking about MLlib alone, but also using some dedicated math framework

Comment: Thanks for the response in the first place. I'm using only Mllib because I have to compute the matrices in parallel since one matrix doesn't fit into the memory of a single machine. Finally I think I will implement the multiplication manually by using CoordinateMatrix of Spark since there isn't a build-in function for doing this using this type of matrix